# Matplotlib is connecting the last to the first point when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, drawing, figure

I am drawing a figure using the script below. When I plot the figure, the last point is connected to the first point. How can I remove this last line drawing ? Note that everything else seems ok.

I have attempted to do a for loop over the first to last point and the result is shown in the below image.

[image]

```
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xValues = []
yValues =[]
for tr in range(105,300,5):
 tr = tr/100.
 for pr in range(0,1500,1):
   pr = pr / 100. 
   result = compressiblityFactor(pr,tr,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11)
   ##result = compressiblityFactor(p,t,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,specificGravity)

   xValues.append((pr))
   yValues.append(result)

pl.plot(xValues,yValues)

pl.show()
```

Comment: If all the values are in the same array or list, there is no "last" and "first" any more.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest There still is *one* "last" and "one" first point. However, there are plenty of points inbetween, connecting the rightmost and leftmost part of the data. (I.e. an `xValue` of 15, followed by an `xValue` of 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the plot in `matplotlib` is drawn:

You send to plot a couple of points and it draws it **from one to another**. In your code you construct several curves but you doesn't draw each of it separately, you send all of them to plot. So it draws the first curve, reaches its end and starts to draw the next. **But!** It doesn't know that there is another curve, it thinks that it is the part of the one very-big-complicated-curve, so the plot draws that annoying line. If you want to draw them separately, you should move `pl.plot(xValues,yValues)` into the first `for` and empty `xValues, yValues` after it. Here is the example of my code (`compressiblityFactor` is replaced by a random func):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import math

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for tr in range(105,300,5):
    xValues = []
    yValues = []
    tr = tr/100.
    for pr in range(0,1500,100):
        pr = pr / 100. 
        result = pr*pr*math.sin(tr*40)
        xValues.append(pr)
        yValues.append(result)
    pl.plot(xValues,yValues)

pl.show()
```

Comment: You could set `xValues` and `yValues` at the beginning of the first for loop to save some screen space ;)

Answer (score 0):

@vurmux has given a great answer to your question. I will just answer this question in a more general sense for those with similar issues. Simply put, matplotlib plot functionality considers all your separate plots as a single curve and it draws "without lifting the pen". These straight lines are drawn when it moves from one curve to another.

We can rewrite/update our xValues(list on x-axis) and yValues(list for y-axis) on each for loop iteration - representing a separate curve - and put the *.show()* function *outside* the for loop.